# PROBLEMA SQL SERVER ROLLBACK trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

good afternoon,
I have a problem with the rollback ... Treger initially was using to call the procedure and the procedure is triggered rollback but it is ...
Now I'm trying to do the rollback from trigger nor ...

attached the code and the error

Thanks for your help

```
USE [Desarrollo_Pruebas]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Prueba_tre]    Script Date: 10/30/2012 17:02:53 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Prueba_tre] 
   ON  [dbo].[Cliente]
    FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON;

begin try
    BEGIN TRAN t1
    SAVE TRAN t1
    INSERT INTO Articulo (Articulo_Codigo, Articulo_Descripcion, Valor_unitario, Categoria_id, msg) VALUES (1040,'EURECA',15000,5,'')
    COMMIT 
    --raiserror ('Test error',16,1)
end try

begin catch
    ROLLBACK TRAN t1
    SELECT    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ERROR_NUMBER, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERROR_MESSAGE;
end catch

--SET NOCOUNT ON;
--exec Prueba CLIENTE_ID;

END
```

Msg 3931, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Prueba_tre, Line 21
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.

THE TABLE IS

the idea is that when I insert into customers products with an insert update ..
at the end of this transaction need to return from the console

```
CREATE TABLE Articulo
(
   Articulo_Codigo int not null primary key
   , Articulo_Descripcion varchar (100)
   , Valor_unitario int
   , Categoria_Id int not null constraint fk_Categoria references Categoria (CATEGORIA_ID)
)

CREATE TABLE Cliente
(
   CLIENTE_ID int not null primary key
   , CLIENTE_PRIMER_NOMBRE varchar(50)
   , CLIENTE_SEGUNDO_NOMBRE varchar(50)
   , CLIENTE_PRIMER_APELLI varchar(50)
   , CLIENTE_SEGUNDO_APELLI varchar(50)
   , CLIENTE_DIRECCION varchar(90)
   , CLIENTE_TELEFONO int
   , CLIENTE_CIUDAD varchar(50)
)
```

Comment: save transaction throwing things off. look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сontinue using procedure. I think you just don't check Exception handling and nested transactions.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Prueba_tre]
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  declare @trancount int;
  set @trancount = @@trancount;
  begin try
    if @trancount = 0
      begin transaction
    else
      save transaction t1

    INSERT INTO Articulo (Articulo_Codigo, Articulo_Descripcion, Valor_unitario, Categoria_id, msg) VALUES (1040,'EURECA',15000,5,'')
    if @trancount = 0 
      commit; 
  end try
  begin catch
    declare @error int, @message varchar(4000 ), @xstate int;
    select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(),
    @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
    @xstate = XACT_STATE();
   if @xstate = -1
     rollback;
   if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
     rollback
   if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
     rollback transaction t1
   raiserror ('t1: %d: %s' , 16, 1, @error, @message)
  end catch
END
```